# Django Rest Framework Pytest Reverse Function Deeper

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-unittest, pytest-django

I am using Django Restframework and try to write unit test cases with pytest. I have been trying to use reverse function for getting the **endpoint path**.

I have generally using this path as like "**reverse("api:death_spec:field_types")**"  generally and it works fine. But if we need go deeper for action method it doesn't work.

My view is:
`class DeathSpecViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

```
@action(detail=False, methods=["get"], url_path=r"(?P<transformation_id>[^/.]+)/case",name="case-list")
def case(self, request, transformation_id):
    dagRunId = self.get_transformation_name()

    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get("page", 1))
        page_size = int(request.GET.get("page_size", 10))
        search = request.GET.get("search")
    except ValueError as e:
        return JsonResponse({"status": False, "message": "Enter a valid data.", "code": 400, "data": []}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    first_data = 0
    if page > 1:
        first_data = page_size * (page - 1)
    last_data = page_size * page
    case_query, total_count = filter_case_list(dagRunId, search, first_data, last_data)
    serializer = CaseListSerializer(case_query, many=True)
    return JsonResponse({"status": True, "message": "Cases listed successfully.", "code": 200, "data": serializer.data, "count": total_count}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)`
```

and my url.py is:

```
from django.urls import path
from apps.death_spec.api.views import *
from rest_framework import routers

app_name = "death_spec"
urlpatterns = [
    path("death-spec/field-types/<str:model_name>", DeathSpecFieldsView.as_view(), name="field_types"),
    path("death-spec/field-names", DeathSpecAllFieldsView.as_view(), name="all_field_names"),
]
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"death-spec", DeathSpecViewSet, basename="death_spec2")
urlpatterns = router.urls + urlpatterns
```

I have been trying to get path with reverse function. So far **"reverse("api:death_spec:death_spec2:case-list"** doesn't work. How can i reach the path with this case?

**This is my unit test**
def test_case(api_client):

```
    url = reverse("api:death_spec:death_spec2:case-list", kwargs={'transformation_id': 70})
    response = api_client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
```

Comment: I've written a tool that can show the `reverse` names for all URLs in your app: https://github.com/valohai/django-urr

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use the `reverse` function to get the URL path for a custom action method in your `DeathSpecViewSet`.
In order to use `reverse` to get the path for a custom action method, you do need to specify the name argument when defining the `@action` decorator for that method.

You have already specified the name argument as "`case-list`" for your case method, so you should be able to get the URL path for that method using the following reverse function call:

```
reverse("api:death_spec:death_spec2:case-list", kwargs={"transformation_id": 70})
```

**Note:** Make sure the `transformation_id` parameter is included in the `kwargs` argument, as it is a required parameter for your case method.

In case this doesn't work, you may want to check that the name argument for your case method is unique among all action methods in your `DeathSpecViewSet`. If there are multiple action methods with the same name argument, `reverse` may not be able to determine which one you are trying to access.

Comment: it still gives error `FAILED apps/death_spec/api/tests/test_deatchspec.py::test_case - django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'death_spec2' is not a registered namespace inside 'api:death_spec'`

Comment: Can you try this reverse("api:death_spec2:case-list", kwargs={"transformation_id": 70})

Comment: Now, it gives error as : **FAILED apps/death_spec/api/tests/test_deatchspec.py::test_case - django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'death_spec2' is not a registered namespace inside 'api'**

Comment: Ok. Can you Try this as well reverse("death_spec2:case-list", kwargs={"transformation_id": 70})

Comment: Now, it gives **FAILED apps/death_spec/api/tests/test_deatchspec.py::test_case - django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'death_spec2' is not a registered namespace**